# When using a while loop in JS, why is it possible to return a value that makes the condition false

Tags: javascript, loops, while-loop, syntax

Depending on where I place the statements inside the while loop, it may or may not return a value that makes the condition false

```
let n = 0;

while (n < 3) {
  n++;
  console.log(n); // Will log 1, 2, and 3
}
```

Whereas if it were written

```
let n = 0;

while (n < 3) {
  console.log(n);
  n++; // Now the program logs 0, 1, and 2
}
```

Shouldn't both cases only log 1 and 2 (and 0 for the second one) since the termination point for the loop is once it reaches 3?
How does this syntax make a difference?

Comment: You *increment `n`*. One time it's before the `console.log` the other after. Why would it log the same stuff when you are performing different steps?

Comment: It seems you might think that the loop automatically exists at any point where the condition becomes false - but this is not the case. The condition is only checked once per iteration, at the start of the loop.

Comment: A while loop will always execute at least once. It checks the condition after executing the statements, and decides whether to go round again.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration#while_statement

Comment: @Mikkel no, a `do..while` loop will execute at least once. `while(false) { console.log("hello") }` will execute zero times

Comment: @Mikkel are you serious? that's what do while does not while if while is false it doesnt execute the body block

Answer (score 1):

Computers don't know loops. They also don't notice when a value in memory changes.

They can only do some very basic math, store things, and do *conditional jumps*. Your while loop basically looks like this internally (pseudocode):

```
 if n smaller 3 jump to end. // conditional jump
 increase n.
 log n.
 jump to first line.
```

So it really doesn't matter when n changes. The loop goes on till the condition is reached again, if the condition is false then, it'll exit there (you can `break;` [jump] out of loops though).